# Php API принятие запросов только с сайта

Tags: javascript, php, api

делаю обработку платежа на сайте. Через js на странице оплаты хочу сделать запрос к API на php, чтобы он отправлял сообщения на почту. Как мне сделать чтобы API могло принять только запрос сгенерированный через js на странице оплаты?
Немного объясню проблему, если я отправлю запрос на API, то его данные будут видны. Пользователь может просто подделать этот запрос и обходить оплату. Если вся обработка оплаты лежит на js. Нужно чтобы API принимало запрос только с моего скрипта. API и скрипт на js находятся на одном сайте.

Comment: Очередной вопрос про то, как бы половчее вырезать гланды автогеном. Через самый низ спины.

А всего-то надо было открыть документацию на платежный гейт, и посмотреть, как **по-человечески** производится прием платежей. Когда факт успешной оплаты подтверждается не колупанием с куличиками и совочком в песочнице, а **запросом, пришедшим с платежного гейта**.

Answer (score 0):

Можно генерировать случайную строку, записывать её в $_SESSION и её же отправлять вместе с данными на странице оплаты (в `<input type="hidden">`, например). И в обработчике формы сверять строку в $_SESSION и ту, что пришла от пользователя.

Comment: Любой пятиклассник нажмет в своем браузере волшебную кнопочку Ctrl-U, и увидит ваш ну очень сикрррретный код во всей красе, и сможет с делать с ним всё что угодно.